# what is the exhaust pressure of bajaj pulsar 220cc engine 2014 model?

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust, turbocharger, pulsar, bajaj

What is the exhaust pressure of Bajaj [Pulsar](http://autos.maxabout.com/bikes/bajaj/pulsar/pulsar-220f) 220cc engine 2014 model?

What is the normal idling rpm of Bajaj Pulsar 220cc?

Can a turbocharger be installed on this bike?

Comment: the turbo installation will cost more than 75% of the bikes total cost and i dont think its possible..

Comment: regarding exhaust pressure.  Can you explain what you want regarding exhaust pressure more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure of the exhaust pressure on that bike check you owners manual, 
The normal idling rpm for the bike would be around 900 to 1100. this can be adjusted by adjusting the idle fuel control knob. do this only after the bike is warm enough.
Regarding the turbo, you can definitely install a turbo on it. I would personally never put a turbo on such engines, there are plenty of chances that you could keep blowing the head gasket, hurt the intake, hurt the carbs. 
Keep in mind that you will have to change a lot of parts like the carbs vacuum lines and a lot.

Comment: You may not trust their engines but they own 25% of KTM since 2007.  Their partnership has been for IP transfer and as well as manufacturing process.  Bajaj has been building motorcycles since 1945 and sold 500,000 in 1950.  You may not trust the product for whattever reason but I believe they have worked very hard with KTM for the liquid cooled twin as well as many other platform improvements on other models from frame to CAN bus and overall manufacturing process development.  Agree with @zaid I think removing the last sentence is in order unless...citations.